# Strange behavior of child node inside matrix node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

The child node behaves strangely within a matrix node.
And it only appears in one matrix node.
I know that there are methods to draw it without the matrix node in this simple case.
But essentially I need to draw the Hasse diagram of a partially ordered set, where each element is a tree.
So it would be nice if the matrix node is kept.
Anyway, the strange behavior is also interesting.
One may also check [child node strangely leaning to the right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569997/tikz-bug-feature-child-node-strangely-leaning-to-the-right) to see that it also appears when using nested tikzpicture.
I am suggested to raise a new question for the case of matrix node.

[image: Two trees next to each other]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [level distance = 10mm]

    \node [matrix, label=left:{$T_1$}] (T1)
    {
            \begin{scope}
                [every node/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=1pt, minimum size = 1mm}]
                \node {}
                child {node {} child {node {}}}
                child {node {} child {node {}}}
                child {node {} child {node {}}};
            \end{scope}\\
        };

    \node [matrix, right = of T1, label=left:{$T_2$}] (T2)
    {
            \begin{scope}
                [every node/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=1pt, minimum size = 1mm}]
                \node {}
                child {node {} child {node {}}}
                child {node {} child {node {}}}
                child {node {} child {node {}}};
            \end{scope}\\
        };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that you not believed to my answer to your previous question. Nesting  TikZ picture inside nodes (matrix is just composition of nodes) lead to unexpected result as you faced now.

Comment: I believe your previous answer. As I explained that I need to draw a Hasse diagram of a poset, so it would be better if there is another solution. Also I am interested in why this unexpected result happens. @Zarko

Comment: @cfr, hm, now I see two possibilities: (i) that my point is lost in translation, (ii) that I'm wrong with my claims :-). I wanted to point out that each tree is a TikZ picture which OP insert in nodes. This is, at least as I know, in the most of cases lead to unexpected result (as OP is faced with).

Comment: @cfr, maybe you're right. This question is repeated https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569997/tikz-bug-feature-child-node-strangely-leaning-to-the-right, for which I suggest to not insert trees in nodes which resulted in correct drawing of trees. With TikZ picture  I meant a picture of a tree composed from nodes inside of `scope`. I'm sorry but it is to early for providing better description, I haven't quite woken up yet :-(

Comment: @Zarko Now I get it. (Early or not.) You're right, but I do think it's a slightly different problem.

Comment: @Zarko No nesting is happening here. It's a matrix with nodes in it, just like every `matrix of nodes`. This is absolutely valid. The problem here is that `right=of …` sets `anchor=west` which all nodes inside the matrix gets inherited, unfortunately.

Comment: @cfr What's wrong with nodes inside a matrix? That's even the whole point of the `matrix` library.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I should have said: nesting nodes/scopes within nodes might be problematic, but it wasn't the same as nesting `tikzpicture`s inside `tikzpicture`s, which definitely is problematic. I don't know why I thought the former was problematic two and a half years ago. Right now, I would say I don't know and would anybody like to find the bug in `chronos`?

Answer (score 1):

The `positioning` library's `right = of …` implicitly sets `anchor = west`. This, unfortunately, gets passed down to the nodes inside the matrix.

We could create extra `positioning` keys for a matrix that use `matrix anchor` instead of `anchor` but in this case, the easiest solution would be to explicitly set `anchor = center` (the default) or `centered` (an alias for `anchor = center`) for all nodes of matrices.

The tree syntax of TikZ is very simple and doesn't set any anchors automatically.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  level distance = 10mm,
  every matrix/.style={
    nodes={draw, circle, inner sep=1pt, minimum size = 1mm, centered}}]
\node [matrix, label=left:{$T_1$}] (T1){
  \node {}
    child {node {} child {node {}}}
    child {node {} child {node {}}}
    child {node {} child {node {}}};\\};
\node [matrix, right = of T1, label=left:{$T_2$}] (T2){
  \node {}
    child {node {} child {node {}}}
    child {node {} child {node {}}}
    child {node {} child {node {}}};\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Or just `right=of …, anchor=center, matrix anchor=west` manually swapping the anchor keys.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the problem seems to be related with `positioning`.
There is a workaround as follows.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [level distance = 10mm]

    \node [matrix, label=left:{$T_1$}] (T1)
    {
            \begin{scope}
                [every node/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=1pt, minimum size = 1mm}]
                \node [grow=down] {}
                child {node {} child {node {}}}
                child {node {} child {node {}}}
                child {node {} child {node {}}};
            \end{scope}\\
        };

    \node [matrix, label=left:{$T_2$}, matrix anchor=west] at ($(T1.east) + (10mm,0)$) (T2)
    {
            \begin{scope}
                [every node/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=1pt, minimum size = 1mm}]
                \node {}
                child {node {} child {node {}}}
                child {node {} child {node {}}}
                child {node {} child {node {}}};
            \end{scope}\\
        };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As Zarko says, this isn't a good idea. Even if it works, it could break suddenly and messily. Usually, such things break at the worst possible moments. Is there any reason to structure the diagram this way? Could you use a tree, for example? Or a single `matrix` to place the nodes and then join them afterwards?